# How to join two tables in different databases in Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

How does one join two tables that are in different databases using the SQL runner in MySQL Workbench?

I have searched for this and explored the interface but could not a find a solution.

If it is not possible with Workbench, is it possible with another client?

**Note:** the databases exist under different connections and ports!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join the table of different database. You need to specify the database name in your FROM clause. To make it shorter, add an ALIAS on it,

```
SELECT  a.*,          -- this will display all columns of dba.`UserName`
  b.`Message`
FROM  dba.`UserName` a  -- or LEFT JOIN to show all rows whether it exists or not
  INNER JOIN dbB.`PrivateMessage` b    
     ON a.`username` = b.`username`
```

So just adding DB name before tablename will solve your problem.

In that Case you can use,FEDERATED Storage Engine to join two mysql connections running on two servers.Please refer doc to know more about it
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! I forgot to include an important detail - the databases exist under different connections and ports!

Comment: Updated the answer...please check FEDERATED Storage Engine for the same

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved if your problem is solved.It can help others looking for the similar problem.